# Show select by value with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have this select:

```html
          <b-form-group
                label-cols-sm="2"
                label-cols-lg="2"
                content-cols-sm
                content-cols-lg="10"
                v-bind:label="$t('vue.contract_terms')"
                label-for="contract_terms"
                v-show="contract">
              <b-form-select
                  :options="contract_terms"
                  v-model="form.contract_data.contract_terms"
                  id="contract_terms"
                  :state="validate(form.contract_data.contract_terms)">
               </b-form-select>
         </b-form-group>
```

i want to show it when in my other select i choose all values except "vat" and "international_contract"

this is my js (hiring_types are the options of my other select) setSelected is my method to show my select above but i want to show it when i choose all values except "vat" and "international_contract":

```js
     data: (instance) => {
            return {
              contract: true,
            }
     },
      computed:{
       hiring_types () {
          return [
            {value: 'contract' , text: this.$t('vue.freelance')},
            {value:'vat' , text: this.$t('vue.employment')},
            {value: 'apprenticeship', text: this.$t('vue.apprenticeship')},
            {value:'co_co_co' , text: this.$t('vue.co_co_co')},
            {value: 'international_contract' , text: this.$t('vue.international_contract')}   
              ]
            },
        },
        methods:{
        setSelected(value) {
             this.hiring_contract_category = value;
             this.contract = value === 'contract';       
            },
        }
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vue's [template conditionals:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

```
  <template v-if='["vat", "international_contract"].map(val => !hiring_types.map(entry => entry.value).includes(val)).every(v => v)'>
  <!-- insert b-form-group -->
  </template>
```

Better to make this conditional a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example) and use it in your template for brevity:

```
// in your script
{
computed: {
  showFormGroup () {
     return ["vat", "international_contract"]
       .map(val => !hiring_types.map(entry => entry.value)includes(val))
       .every(v => v)
  }
}

// in your template
<template v-if='showFormGroup'> ... </template>
```